# How to use OS-provided toolchain within conda?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, installer-anaconda

On Ubuntu 18.04 I run `which gcc` and the output is as expected.

```
ubuntu@USER1:~$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

However when I activate my `conda` environment and run `which gcc` I get:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@USER1:~$ which gcc
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/gcc
```

This location seems strange to me. I wan to use the normal system wide `gcc`.

I know this is not default behaviour as in my other Ubuntu instance when I run `which gcc` the output is correct:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@USER2:~$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

How can I get `conda` to use the default `gcc` as shown with `USER2`?

---

**EDIT:**

`USER1` instance: `conda 4.5.12`

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@USER1:~$ gcc -v
Reading specs from /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/specs
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix 
gcc version 4.8.5 (GCC)
```

but

```
ubuntu@USER1:~$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```